# React/MaterialUI - Change case on button click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a Switch where a user selects a gender and then gets the appropriate form. The forms have been created as components and render fine when I set the gender manually. Where I am stuck is getting the gender variable to update when a user clicks a button. I understand this is probably not the right way, and I should use State, but my google-fu is failing me, so I am asking you experts. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component, constructor } from "react";
import MaleHormone from "../components/maleHormone"
import FemaleHormone from "../components/femaleHormone"
import { Button, Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

var gender = ""

export default class Hormones extends Component {

  genderSwitch(gender: any) {
    switch (gender) {
      case "Male":
        return (<MaleHormone />);
      case "Female":
        return (<FemaleHormone />);
      default:
        return (<Grid
        container
        spacing={6}
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          padding: 20,
          paddingTop: 100,
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}>
          <Typography variant="h4" color="primary">
            Please select your gender
          </Typography>
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={6}
            style={{
              textAlign: "center",
              minHeight: 20,
              padding: 20,
              paddingTop: 30,
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
            >
            <Button id="male" value="Male" variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large" style={{marginRight: 20}}>
              Male
            </Button>
            <Button id="female" value="Female" variant="contained" color="secondary" size="large">
              Female
            </Button>
          </Grid>
      </Grid>);
    }
  }

  render() {
      return (
      this.genderSwitch(gender)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Make gender a state instead of a var, and change it using setState. When you select a gender, it will re-render, go through your switch, and select the correct form to render

Comment: Thank you Ferran. That is where I am struggling. I tried a few times to use constructor and set a state but I kept getting code errors in VS and compile issues. Can you give me a clue to get me on the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,  this should work:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MaleHormone from "../components/maleHormone"
import FemaleHormone from "../components/femaleHormone"
import { Button, Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";



export default class Hormones extends Component {
  state = {
    gender: ""
  };

  genderSwitch(gender: any) 
  {
    switch (gender) 
    {
      case "Male":
        return <MaleHormone />;

      case "Female":
        return <FemaleHormone />;

      default:
        return (
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={6}
            style={{
              textAlign: "center",
              padding: 20,
              paddingTop: 100,
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="h4" color="primary">
              Please select your gender
            </Typography>
            <Grid
              container
              spacing={6}
              style={{
                textAlign: "center",
                minHeight: 20,
                padding: 20,
                paddingTop: 30,
                justifyContent: "center"
              }}
            >
              <Button
                id="male"
                value="Male"
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                size="large"
                style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                onClick = {() => this.setState({gender:"Male"})}
              >
                Male
              </Button>
              <Button
                id="female"
                value="Female"
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                size="large"
                onClick = {() => this.setState({gender:"Female"})}

              >
                Female
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    let genderForm = this.genderSwitch(this.state.gender);

    return genderForm;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did it! As a note, "return { genderForm }" threw an error about Objects not being valid as a React child. Removing the brackets resolved the error.

Comment: Yeah, you are right , i forgot about the return statement not being wrapped with ( ) . i will edit the answer. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

```
import {TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
export default class Hormones extends Component {
    state = {gender: "Male"}

    ...

    render () {
        return (
            <>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> { 
                    this.setState(
                      {
                          gender: this.state.gender==="Male"?"Female":"Male"
                      });
                    }
                >
                    <Text>Switch Gender</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                this.switchGender(this.state.gender);
            </>
        );
    }
}
```